Unit test IonInput parameter in Ionic Angular with Jasmine: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
In this setter inside a custom input component I want to make a test in Jasmine that passes through the getInputElement function.
@ViewChild('customInput')
public set customInput(value: IonInput) {
    value.getInputElement().then(() => this.registerTextMask());
}

After initializing the tests in the component with this beforeEach I get the error
TypeError: value.getInputElement is not a function
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateLoaderMock }
            }),
        ],
        declarations: [CustomInputComponent],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
});

Later I added the IonicModule import to add the Ionic configuration to the tests and now I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
            at apply (node_modules/@ionic/angular/fesm2015/ionic-angular.js:356:71)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:375:26)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:39)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:374:52)
            at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:134:43)
            at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:24212:28)
            at IonInput.getInputElement (node_modules/@ionic/angular/fesm2015/ionic-angular.js:356:27)
            at CustomInputComponent.set customInput [as customInput] (src/app/components/custom-input/custom-input.component.ts:39:11)
            at viewQueryFn (ng:///CustomInputComponent.js:20:76)
            at executeViewQueryFn (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:11649:5)

This is the HTML of the ion-input:
<ion-input #customInput id="custom" [ariaLabel]="ariaLabel | translate" name="custom" type="tel" maxlength={{max}} clear-on-edit="true"
      [maskito]="customMaskOptions" [maskitoElement]="maskPredicate" [formControl]="customNumber"
      [placeholder]="'WEEK.dateFormat' | translate" [value]="currentDate">
</ion-input>

I can't come up with any idea to avoid the errors and to enter the promise at the same time. How can I solve this? Is there any way to mock the value parameter?

please share the related html for customInput!

I've just added the HTML to the description.
